# How to force my model heads to learn different things?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-function, optimization, sequence-to-sequence, multitask-learning

I have an Seq2Seq model that has 2 generative LM heads. I want the two heads to focus on different features/styles while decoding. The approach that I was thinking of is adding a distance cost to the existing loss function in a multitask framework. Assuming my two heads give me two different probability distributions, let's say $prob_1$ and $prob_2$ over the vocabulary. I want to have a Loss function to be something like
$$ Final Loss = CrossEntropyLoss(f(prob_1,prob_2), targetDistribution) - \lambda * dist(prob_1, prob_2)$$.
Assume f is some way of combining the two distributions for the final output (like a simple gating function). What is the best way to approach this? For the distance function, I was thinking of using something like symmetric KL divergence, although I know maximizing this KL divergence is perhaps not a well-conditioned optimization problem. Another thought was using cosine distance. Pushing the cosine similarity to 0 would be in some way force the model to learn orthogonal information(?), but would that work in practice given the fact that expected cosine similarity for random large dimensional vectors goes down with the size of the vectors? Also, what is the best way to set the value of lambda, given I still want generally good results that are learned from the CEL function, but the two different loss functions can have drastically different magnitudes such that it is good enough to minimize one. Basically what I am asking is

1. What is the best way/framework to force my two heads to learn different information while still being performant in terms of the seq2seq task learnt through the CEL?
2. How to best set the optimization problem such that there is a cost associated with the two heads learning the same distribution
3. how to scale the two losses(how to determine value of lambda) in the setting that doing multitask learning is really the best framework for my goals ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.